# How to read 'etc' in English?

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

'You hang up hurriedly and attend to baby,crockery,etc', could you please tell me how to read 'etc'? just read the letters one by one or there is another way to read it?

Comment: Why didn't the [pronunciation for "etc" in the dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/etc#etc__3) you found when you looked it up help you?

Comment: You can also take a look at Forvo: https://forvo.com/search/etc./en/ (although remember that the site is crowdsourced, so it's not authoritative)

Comment: That forvo link pronounces the word properly as a stand-alone word, but as "ets" in the sentence. :(

Answer (score 6):

*Etc* is an abbreviation of the Latin phrase *et cetera* (meaning "and the rest"). In English, it is pronounced as the entire phrase (even if it is abbreviated).  The "c" in "cetera" is soft in modern English, so it sounds like an "s".

Comment: When I am **reading in my head** I often pronounce it as its own word: *etss*. But definitely agree that when spoken aloud, "etc" is pronounced "ett settera."

Comment: and not eggs setera